# Cannot read property length of undefined - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm new in javascript the main goal of this code is to type a question in the textbox the browser will check the question if it was in the switches statements and get the answer than write it on the paragraph's id="lable".

- The function randomArray(z)-line[8]- return a random array value .

#### What's hapenning :

**Typed :"undefined" on the paragraph which has "lable" as an id .**
**.........................**
The HTML code :

```
<body>
<img src="Alexs_face.png">
    <p style="border:2px black solid; margin:100px 400px 50px 400px">Ask me     !</p>
<p id="lable"></p>
<input id="input" type="text" autocomplete="off">
<input id="send" type="button" onclick="dosome()"  value="Send">
<input id="delete" type="button" onclick="deleteVal()"  value="Delete"></body>
```

The Javascript:

```
var greating , userName;



var firstHello = [[greating+userName+", How can I help you ?" ], ["Hi  "+userName+" how can i help ?"] ,[ greating+", how can i help ?"]];

dosome () ;

function randomArray (z) {  
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * z.length);
return z[index];
};

 function getVal() {
write(randomArray (firstHello)); /* <------ trying to write a radom  value from the firstHello array
*/
 var ask = document.getElementById("input").value;
return ask ;}
var ask = getVal();
function write (x){
var lable = document.getElementById("lable").innerHTML = x;
return lable ;
};

//Capitalize the first letters func :
function capitalize(string) {
return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
//..............







//............................... you can ignore this function
function dosome () {

var ask = getVal();
var question = ask.split(" ");
var date = new Date().toTimeString().split(" ")[0]; ;
var userName ="Med" ;

 //5// give you different "greatings" according to ur time

 if (date >= "06:00:00" && date <="11:00:00"){
 greating = "Good morning ";
 var alertTime=""
}
else if (date >= "11:00:00" && date <= "15:00:00"){
greating = "Good afternoon ";
var alertTime=""
}
else if (date >= "15:00:00" && date <="22:00:00"){
greating = "Good evening ";
var alertTime=""
}
else {
greating = " You should have some sleep !";
 var alertTime = greating ; 
};
//5//end

//
if (question[0] === "what"){
switch ( question[1]){

case "time":
            switch (question[2]){
                case "is":
                          switch (question[3]){
                          case "it":
                          write("The time is :"+date+alertTime);
                          break;
                          default:
                          };
                break;
            default:    
            } ;
 break;
case "is":
          switch (question[2]){
              case "your" :
                           switch (question[3]){
                           case "name":
                           write("Alex !");
                           break;
                           case "father":
                           write("Medardo Erabti , he made me !");
                           break;
                           default:
                           };
              break;
              case "my":
              switch (question[3]){
                           case "name":
                           write("Alex !");
                           break;


                           default:
                           };
              break;
              default:

          };
break;

default: write("unknown");

};}
else if (question[0] === "my"){

switch (question[1]){
case "name":
           switch(question[2]){
               case "is":

                userName = capitalize(question[3]);;
                alert("Your name is saved, "+userName);
               break;

              default: 
           };
break;



default:
};
}
else if (question[0] === "should" || "could" || "may" || "can" )  {


switch (question[1]) {
case "i" :
      switch(question[2]){
      case "sleep":
      write("Sure ! you can sleep if you want to !!");
      break;
      default:
      }
break;

default:
};

}
if (question[0] === "who"){

switch (question[1]){

case "are":
write ("I'm Alex !");
break;
case "am":
write ("My leader !");
default:
 }

};

return userName,greating ;
};
function deleteVal () {

var x = document.getElementById("lable").innerHTML = "" ;
return x ;
};
```

- What I have tried:

Tried to disable the 'z' parametr in the function 'randomArray(z)' and replace it with the name of the array "firstHello" , Its type "undefined in the paragraf that has "lable" as an id .

Comment: On a sidenote . it's "greetings" not "greatings"

Comment: Sorry , Italian is my first lanuage. @zeropublix

Comment: @zeropublix: The `firstHello` variable is global, so it can be used from anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Guffa: nope. Writing "var" in front means it's not global . if you would leave out the "var" it would be global. Correct me with source if I'm wrong

Comment: @zeropublix: Using `var` only makes a function local if the code is inside a function. When the code is in the global scope the variable will be global.

Comment: @Guffa: tryed it. Your right . my bad. Thanks. I confused it with using variables through different script-files scope.

Answer (score 1):

In the `dosome` function you create a local variable named `userName`, the same as the global variable. The local variable will shadow the global variable for the code inside the function, so the global variable will still be undefined after calling the function.

Notes about the code in the `randomArray` function:

- You are using `Math.floor` instead of `Math.random`.
- Don't use `Math.round` when creating an integer random number, that will make the first and last number occur half as often as the other numbers. Use `Math.floor` instead.
- Your loop goes two items beyond the last item in the array.
- You don't need to loop at all to get an item with a specific index.

Here is code that just shows the modified `randomArray` function and code to call it:

```js
var greating = 'Hello', userName = 'sir';

var firstHello = [
  [ greating + " " + userName + ", How can I help you ?" ],
  [ "Hi " + userName + " how can i help ?" ],
  [ greating + ", how can i help ?" ]
];

function randomArray(z) {  
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * z.length);
  return z[index];
}

console.log(randomArray(firstHello));
```

Comment: Hi , thanks for reply , I edited the loop , but what shall i do with the two variables ? @Guffa

Comment: @15YO-m: Remove the `var` in `var userName ="Med" ;` so that it sets the global variable instead.